# How to properly implement web services in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services

Currently in my PHP-based applications I use a file, for instance **services.php** and call it via AJAX to return the appropriate data.

To call a certain method, I send a parameter in the GET. For instance **services.php?action=read_article**. From this point, it'll hit a huge switch statement until it finds the appropriate case and returns the data I'm looking for.

Technically, everything works properly, but I can't help but feel that it isn't the *right* way to do it.

Is there a better way to implement web services in PHP?

Comment: Judging from your description there is, but take into account there is no golden way that fits everything, so if your project works well as it is, and there are no bottlenecks in the way your code executes it at the moment, then your way can also be the best way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action switch is fine, if your using OOP you can have it call various methods to keep it small like..

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case "blah":
        return $this->doBlah();
        break;
    case "foo":
        return $this->doFoo();
        break;
    default:
        return $this->doError();
}
```

Alternatively you could do what other frameworks do and map a URL into a method like..

```
/services/read/
```

Maps to class "Services" and method "Read" take a look at Codeigniter for how they do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) is a very nice tutorial on how to create a RESTful api using PHP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18997616)

Comment: Darn, you're just a few years too late! Looks like the link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like amfphp, it integrates into many languages and apps, and you can write your own service classes to handle almost any input/output based on what you need. I reuse the same service for iphone, android and pc. link: http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/